# Compile php-interbase

Tags: php, firebird

am on 64bit Linux trying to compile PHP --with-interbase=/opt/firebird

This results in

```
checking for InterBase support... yes
checking for isc_detach_database in -lfbclient... no
checking for isc_detach_database in -lgds... no
checking for isc_detach_database in -lib_util... no
configure: error: libgds, libib_util or libfbclient not found! Check config.log for more information.
```

The libfclient etc ARE there. Looking at config.log there are plenty of errors when it tries to check interbase:

```
configure:50792: gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -pthread  -D_REENTRANT -L/opt/firebird//lib -L/usr/lib  -L/usr/local/lib conftest.c -lfbclient  $
/opt/firebird//lib/libfbclient.so: undefined reference to `std::bad_alloc::~bad_alloc()'
/opt/firebird//lib/libfbclient.so: undefined reference to `__cxa_pure_virtual'
/opt/firebird//lib/libfbclient.so: undefined reference to `__cxa_rethrow'
/opt/firebird//lib/libfbclient.so: undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
/opt/firebird//lib/libfbclient.so: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
```

Comment: After a bit more testing I find that this problem is specific to Superserver..  So with Firebird compiled with --enable-superserver. I would prefer superserver so any thoughts on why this makes a difference would be helpful

Answer (score 5):

Hint for docker users: Make sure to install `firebird-dev` in your Dockerfile.

```
RUN apt-get -y install firebird-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install interbase
RUN docker-php-ext-enable interbase
```

Comment: Thanks, needed that to add pdo_firebird with `docker-php-ext-install`

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be due to a 64 bit difference in the libfbclient.so files that are required by PHP.  I had this very same issue, and eventually found that installing the latest Firebird AMD64 build of v2.1 Super Server did the trick.  I installed this via RPM rather than trying to build from scratch, after first uninstalling any previous FB installations, and then magically my PHP configure completed successfully.  HTH.